# How to get the setting string (like buildpath = /home/build ) using regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex

My string is like this(xcode project settings):

```
ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS = armv7 armv7s
AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS = iphonesimulator macosx iphoneos
BUILD_COMPONENTS = headers build
BUILD_DIR = /home/projects/build
BUILD_ROOT = /home/ohter/build
```

I wan to get the string "/home/projects/build" whitch "BUILD_DIR = " at its head. and a \n at the end.

I want using regular expressions in python . I read a lot of doc about the regular expressions but I can't understand very quickly. Anybody can give me some tip ?

Comment: No one understands regular expressions very quickly. They're hard.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions can be very attractive, but in general you want to avoid them whenever possible. They tend to be relatively difficult to comprehend, prone to error, and inflexible.

Instead, I would suggest something closer to this (assuming you're reading this string in from a file):

```
def grab_parameter(filename, parameter):
    with open(filename) as source:
        for line in source:
            if line.startswith(parameter):
                return line.split('=')[1].strip()

print grab_parameter('my_settings.txt', 'BUILD_DIR')
>>> /home/projects/build
```

This way, your usage becomes very flexible, and if you decided to grab another variable you could do it easily, for instance:

```
print grab_parameter('my_settings.txt', 'BUILD_COMPONENTS')
>>> headers build
```

You COULD do this with regular expressions, by using a regex like this:

```
r'BUILD_DIR\s?\=\s?(.*?)'
```

But as you can see, it's a pretty unattractive prospect. It's unclean, unintuitive, and generally very brittle (not to mention that you get weird SOH characters popping up).

If you REALLY want to use regex (which you shouldn't), you could do it like so:

```
import re

def grab_build_dir(filename):
    re_pattern = re.compile(r'BUILD_DIR\s?\=\s?(.*?)')
    with open(filename) as source:
        for line in source:
            if re.match(re_pattern, line):
                return re.sub(re_pattern, '\1', line)

print grab_parameter('my_settings.txt', 'BUILD_DIR')
>>> \x01/home/projects/build
```

Comment: In this case, I agree. I'd forget regular expressions and use Python's [configuration module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). This is very close to an ini file. It might need a section header, but I think that's all.

Comment: @jpmc26 Totally agree, but I'd rather tilt the heading than spin the ship around.